# HTML tag <pre> is inserted on moodle ajax response when send a message on chat tool

Tags: php, html, ajax, apache, moodle

When I send a message on moodle (Moodle 3.3) chat tool, the response is returning a `<pre>` tag that is making all the JS behaviour fails (because it makes itself an invalid json). This is causing the alert with "undefined" error. Any idea about how can I solve this?

I think it could be something about apache or php configuration, because it is working properly on my local machine, but failing on production server (same code on both sides).

[Error response (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H5C8.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @user3783243 is the standard code of Moodle 3.3.